# Convert String to date in to yyyy-MM-dd for jUnit test

Tags: java, date, junit

I am doing junit test for a method in the dao layer which requires to pass date value in the format to use in the SQL query. I have the date string `"2006-08-14"` and tried to convert into date using the following code.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date2 = sdf.parse("2006-08-14");
...
projectSchedule.setDate(date2);
```

The above code sets the value as

```
 Mon Aug 14 00:00:00 GST 2006
```

This fails in the DAO layer because the query expects the date in the format yyyy-MM-dd

```
select * from projects_bidders pb, projects_bidders_type pbt  where   cde_project = :projectId and cde_phase = :phaseId and  phase_start_date =  :phaseDate and foreign_id is not null and id_bidder = cde_bidder
```

`query.setParameter("phaseDate", projectSchedule.getDate());`

I referred many questions in in SO and didn't find any thing suitable.

I don't have control on DAO layer.

Comment: Can you post and example API of the DAO layer

Comment: `Date`s don't have formats. The output is just the result of its `toString()`.

Comment: ...to clarify: You already have a `Date` object that you can ‘pass to the DAO layer’. Never mind that output, it's just a string *representation* of the `Date`.

Comment: @Biffen Thanks, I can pass this date to DAO layer,and in DAO I can convert the date to string and use in the SQL query. But in case if we don't have the control of the code which I want to test?

Comment: @shams Not sure I fully understand. If the API takes a `Date` object, give it a `Date` object. A `Date` object has no format on its own. A date *string* on the other hand has, and when you want to convert a `Date` to a `String` that's when you specify the format.

Comment: @shams - I think you need to specify your requirements more clearly. Questions often get put on hold if people can not understand exactly what your asking for and why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Date` objects don't have a format. When you parse any object into a call to `System.out.println()` that objects' `toString()` method is called. `Date`'s `toString()` method always returns a `String` in that format.

For functionality like you describe you would have to subclass `Date` and override `toString()` like so;

```
class FormattedDate extends Date {

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        return sdf.format(this);
    }

}
```

Your DOA, would of course need knowledge of the new `FormattedDate` class.

---

**Edit Following Question Update;**

*Given that you have no control of the DOA or the SQL database software directly there is no way of changing the format the database software displays the date in. The datebase simply takes a `Date` object, which is a representation of the number of miliseconds since `0 am January 1st 1970`. The database **software** specifies how the dates are formatted, which you can not change except by changing the database access software's settings.*

*If you need to then fetch the date and display it in your own software, you will need to reformat it on your end because the data in the database probably doesn't have a format. A date's format, and data representing a date are entirely different constructs. Dates and Formats are entirely seperate, even in the database.*